# VideoView throws IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have a videoview in my app which plays videos from my expansion file. Here is the code:

```
private VideoView _vv;
    private static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://--PACKAGENAMEHIDDENFORSECURITY--.EHZipUriProvider");
    private static final String VIDEO_NAME  = "b1.mp4";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);
    _vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vv);

    startVideoPlayback();
}

private void startVideoPlayback()
{
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(_vv);

    _vv.setMediaController(mediaController);
    _vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI + "/" + VIDEO_NAME));
    _vv.start();
}
```

And the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepareAsync(Native Method)
            at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:335)
            at android.widget.VideoView.access$2100(VideoView.java:71)
            at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:607)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:572)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1897)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
            ...
```

I have no idea why it does this. Can anyone help?

My layout is just a videoview.

Comment: Check out this https://github.com/protocol10/SangeetPlayer/blob/master/src/com/akshay/sangeetplayer/video/Video_Player.java

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
try {


        mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        Uri video = Uri.parse(url);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);

        videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                videoView.start();
            }
        });
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Comment: this code is of a project that i used, and here work